# Adding Whey Protein to fitness goal

Tags: nutrition, protein, protein-shakes

Some background - Its been around 8 months since I have been exercising regularly, I am 178 cm tall, used to weigh 52.4 Kg when I had started, I have increased to 57.8 till date. Though I was advised about whey protein all along in the beginning I ignored it thinking it was a supplement, it affects kidneys, I can consume that much protein in chicken and fish etc.

Now at this point, I think the gains have not been as much as I had anticipated, mainly because of not reaching the daily protein intake on some days as I don't eat meat daily.

So is it a good idea to consider taking whey protein? How much, which brand? Or just keep on going as it is and reach my goal of 64? Also, once I decide to stop taking it, will it affect my weight?

Comment: Whey protein is great but it is a supplement.  It is meant to supplement eating real food.  You need to eat real food to gain weight.  Just increasing your protein will not help you gain weight.  Increasing carbohydrates and fats will help you gain weight.

Answer (score 5):

Whey protein is used to gain muscle mass fast. Its a supplement and has very little side effects. The Brand is important because some people see more improvement with diffirent brands(needs to be verified). But **ON** is the leading provider by far, having the most reputation among bodybuilders.

How much: There is no universal answer to this particular question since everybody's protein needs vary. Protein requirements vary depending on an individual's age, gender, weight, medical conditions and the nature of the workout one does.

When: The best results can be seen when Whey protein is consumed in the morning, after a workout. If you exercise regularly, it may be best to consume a Whey protein shake immediately following a workout. A report published by the National Strength and Conditioning Association recommends consuming at least 15g of protein after each workout.

Your body is highly sensitive to insulin after exercise and shuttles carbohydrates and proteins into muscle cells instead of fat cells. This sensitivity declines post-workout until ~2 hours at which point it reaches baseline.

Answer (score 1):

Using a good Whey protein shake can be a great way to supplement your protein intake.

you can check bodybuilding.com and read-up about good reputable brands & their products,, a few that come to mind are Muscletech, Optimum Nutrion, BSN, Gaspari etc...

- Follow the instructions on the container.
- Since your natural & this IS NOT DRUGS, as long as you keep training & keep eating after you stop using it, you weight wont/shouldn't drop.

Comment: What do you mean by "Since your natural"?